# JavaScript Snippet not working in Ruby on Rails View

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-4

Here's the snippet.  It's not syncing to my api app. I'm running both locally, the api app and the application that I'm tracking.

```
<script> 
(function (){
    // track a client-side event using the metrics analytics service
  var _bm_event = {
    name: "Topic Views",
    topic_name: "<%= @topic.name %>",
    created_at: "<%= @topic.created_at %>"
  }

  var _bm_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  _bm_request.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000/events", true);
  _bm_request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  _bm_request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    // this function runs when the Ajax request changes state.
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest
  };
  _bm_request.send(JSON.stringify(event));
}());</script>
```

Any insight or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you got any authentication on your API? What about any errors returned by the Javascript log?

Comment: I don't have any authentication on my API. It's a custom one that I'm creating.  Also, I only started using Firebug yesternite, so not too familiar with it

Comment: ok, it's not showing up in the Javascript console on Firebug

Comment: The problem was a follows.     _bm_request.send(JSON.stringify(event) 

should be

 _bm_request.send(JSON.stringify(_bm_event)

and 

    (function (){
should be

    $(document).ready(function (){